# Remove element from admin page editing part

Tags: pages, admin

I would like to remove few element in the admin page editing part.

Here a screen to the elements I want to remove.

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: can you edit your question to mention why and add some context? This is important as what you're asking removes critical parts of the editor that would break a lot of things, more than you expect. Also 2 circled items are from 3rd party plugins/themes, you can't ask how to remove the Elementor button in the top left as questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, you also can't ask about Astra functionality. Each of the items circled could have been their own question which would have gotten you faster/better answers

Comment: You are right thanks for you advice I will split my question ! Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.